# Specifying exact path for my ASP.NET Http Handler

Tags: asp.net, web-config, httphandler

I generate an XML/Google sitemap on the fly using an Http Handler, so that I don't need to maintain an XML file manually.

I have mapped my Http Handler to "sitemap.xml" in my web.config like this:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="sitemap.xml" type="My.Name.Space, MyAssembly" />
</httpHandlers>
```

It works nicely. Now, www.mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml sets my Http Handler into action and does exactly what I want. However, this url will do the same: www.mywebsite.com/some/folder/sitemap.xml and I don't really want that i.e. I just want to map my handler to the root of my application.

I have tried changing the "path" of my handler in my web.config to "/sitemap.xml" and "~/sitemap.xml" but neither works.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the following to your web.config

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
    <add url="~/SiteMap.xml" mappedUrl="~/MyHandler.ashx"/>
</urlMappings>
```

This uses a little known feature of ASP.NET 2.0 called ['Url Mapping'](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3581326)

Comment: That's more like what I'm after, but now it requires a physical .ashx file and at the moment I don't have that - just a class implementing IHttpHandler, no physical file in my web project. I will use this method IF there are no better suggestions...

Comment: You can just create a ashx file in you web application pointing to your handler in another assembly like this: 
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="MyHandlersNamespace.MyHandler, MyHandler" %>

Here I refer to a handler in another assembly called 'MyHandlers'

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Kirtan suggested solution #1 you can do a workaround like follows:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
  //Ensure that the sitemap.xml request is to the root of the application
  if (!context.Request.PhysicalPath.Equals(Server.MapPath("~/sitemap.xml"))) {
     //Invoke the Default Handler for this Request
     context.RemapHandler(null);
  }

  //Generate the Sitemap
}
```

You might need to play with this a bit, not sure if invoking the default handler will just cause IIS to re-invoke your Handler again.  Probably worth testing in Debug mode from VS.  If it does just re-invoke then you'll need to try invoking some static file Handler instead or you could just issue a HTTP 404 yourself eg

```
//Issue a HTTP 404
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
return;
```

See the MSDN documentation on HttpContext.RemapHandler for more info - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.remaphandler.aspx

Comment: Had a go at this and ended up issuing the 404 myself as suggested above. Handler's code still gets run but only if a page that doesn't exist is requested.

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions to this:

Soln #1:
You can check the request path using the Request.Url property, if the request is from the root path, you can generate the XML, else don't do anything.

Soln #2:
Put a web.config file with the following setting in every folder in which you don't want to handle the request for the sitemap.xml file.

Comment: Solution 1 still means by handler's code gets run. I don't want that. I want to only run it when a specific URL (the root) gets requested. Admittedly, this is my fallback.

Solution 2 isn't really an option: putting a web.config in every directory! What if I have hundreds of directories?

Answer (score 0):

You can, alternately, run a check in the global.asax, verify the request, and finaly re-assigning a new handler throughtout context.RemapHandler method.
The only thing is that you would´ve to implement a factory for that matter.

I would suggest you inherit the HttpApplication, and implement there the factory, but that's your call.