# transfer sitemap.xml http request to route handler in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to add a route that will transfer all `sitemap.xml` requests to a custom request handler I made.

I tried using the following code:

```
        routes.Add(new Route("sitemap.xml", new Helpers.SiteMapRouteHandler()));
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  
        );
```

But when I make a link using `Url.Action()`:

```
Url.Action("Index", new { controller = "About"})
```

I get the following when I try to navigate to the XML file:

```
/sitemap.xml?action=Index&controller=About
```

What am I doing wrong?

ANSWER:

I used this solution:

[Specifying exact path for my ASP.NET Http Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700443/specifying-exact-path-for-my-asp-net-http-handler)

Comment: where do you have it in your list of routes? It appears pretty generic, so it would be matching on all requests. You may want to use Phil Haack's Route Debugger to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to route to and action instead to a request handler

You could add a route like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Sitemap",
        "sitemap.xml",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "SiteMap" }
        );
```

as mentioned here - [MVC: How to route /sitemap.xml to an ActionResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006529/mvc-how-to-route-sitemap-xml-to-an-actionresult) and it worked for me

**Update:** Also ensure that `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` is set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve the problem, but it's worth a try:

```
routes.Add(
    new Route(
        "{request}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = "" }),  // this might be the tricky part to change
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { request = "sitemap.xml" }),
        new Helpers.SiteMapRouteHandler()
    ));
```

Comment: no, it doesnt work. I get HTTP 404 when trying to get /sitemap.xml

Comment: Wish I could have been more help.  Only other thing I can think of is to try setting both RVD to (new { request = "sitemap.xml" })

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a handler to web.config file.

```
<add name="SitemapFileHandler" path="sitemap.xml" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
```

And configure your routes:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Read more here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works